# Loop and concatenate same VAR

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Is it possible to use `do{}while()` to concatenate the same var depending on the result of another var?

I am running a loop where I capture Customers and their Payments, each line is a result, sometimes for the same customer I have 2 or more Payments, i.e:

`Customer A --- 'Payment#01' --- $10.00
 Customer A --- 'Payment#02' --- $10.00
 Customer B --- 'Payment#01' --- $10.00
 Customer B --- 'Payment#02' --- $10.00
 Customer B --- 'Payment#03' --- $10.00
 [...]`

I want to check the customer on the first line and `while` the next line continues with the same customer I'd like to concatenate each result in one string, so I will have something like this:

`Customer A --- 'Payment#01,Payment#02' --- $20.00
 Customer B --- 'Payment#01,Payment#02,Payment#03' --- $30.00`

[Edit: code so far]

```
try{
    do{
        resultSet = searchResults.getResults(resultIndex, resultIndex + resultStep); 
        resultIndex = resultIndex + resultStep; 
        for(var i = 0; !!resultSet && i < resultSet.length; i++){
            var results = resultSet[i];
            var columns = results.getAllColumns();
            var customer = results.getValue(columns[0]);
            var paymentamt = results.getValue(columns[1]);
            var document = results.getValue(columns[2]);
        } 
    } while (!!resultSet && resultSet.length > 0)
} catch(error){
    var message = error.message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the customers are always in a neat order, ie you won't ever get Customer A, Customer B, Customer A, then just use a variable to keep track of the current customer ID, current payment string, and current value.

Loop through the lot - is the customer ID at [loop] the same as the current one? If yes, add to the string and value.
If not, output (or whatever you do with it) the current line, reset all the variables to this new customer's data.

If they can arrive *out* of order then you could store the values in an object - eg. customerRecord = {customerID : { paymentstring:, value:}}.
As you read in the next customer in the loop, check if it exists in the object (hasOwnProperty if you use the customerID as a key as above) and add to its values. If not, add a new object to customerRecord.

Comment: You should provide some code and a better formatted version of  the key value structure in order to make your answer more readable. Your answer is correct, though people might tl;dr it because it looks like a bile of text rather than a usable solution. Just a tip, no judgment.

Comment: Thanks @WindsorAndy, 
Answering your question: they are always sorted by customer in sequence.

I have an idea of what you suggested, but I am not a developer, I am learning js reading help documentation and articles all over the place, so I understand your logic but I am lacking for syntaxes to build this loop =/

This is what I have so far, I have already a loop because I am looping through all the results, so I imagine I need another loop inside:

Answer (score 0):

The most generic approach is to keep an object with keys or the more modern `Map` to keep the totals and all payments. The most direct approach would be to keep objects and simply keep appending the string. An alternative is to keep the separate payments (descriptions) inside those objects and only concatenate them when displaying. For example:

```js
//this part is just for emulating the resultset
let resultSet =[ {vals:['Customer A' ,'Payment#01' ,10.00]},  {vals:['Customer A' ,'Payment#02' ,10.00]},  {vals:['Customer B' ,'Payment#01' ,10.00]},  {vals:['Customer B' ,'Payment#02' ,10.00]},  {vals:['Customer B' ,'Payment#03' ,10.00]}  ];resultSet.forEach(o=> {o.getAllColumns = ()=> [0,1,2]; o.getValue = i => o.vals[i]});
  

let map = new Map(); // <- declare outside the do..while , if it should concatenate customers from all searches, otherwise inside
do{
 //get result set code...
 if(!resultSet)break;
   for(var i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++){    
            let results = resultSet[i],
             columns = results.getAllColumns();
              customer = results.getValue(columns[0]),
             tot = map.get(customer);
            if(!tot) map.set(customer,tot = {customer:customer, payments:[], totalAmt:0, get Payments(){return this.payments.join(', ');} , toString: function(){return `${this.customer} --- ${this.Payments} --- ${this.totalAmt}`;}});
            tot.payments.push(results.getValue(columns[1]));
            tot.totalAmt += results.getValue(columns[2]);
        }     
}while(false); //replace with your own while (since break is used, you could simply do while(true))

//test output code. 
for(let tot of map.values())
 console.log(tot.toString());
```